# Thread has been active for xxxx milliseconds and may be Hung - At a While Loop that Modifies int primitive in Method Execution

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, websphere, java-threads

Given below is the code Snippet that is in a Groovy util file and getting called from a different groovy file, which is basically getting invoked from a Java class using Java.lang.groovyObject.invokeMethod(methodName, paramvalues)

Param values at Run Time : 0 and 4708 for x and y.

While Running as part of the application in WebSphere, there are several hung thread issues reported exactly on the line
`inc +=base`
,which is inside the while loop.
The error and the trace are as follows,

ThreadMonitor W WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 2" (000001b0) has been active for 607463 milliseconds and may be hung. There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in that server that may be hung.

at xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.getIncrementValue(FileName:LinNumber)
.
.
at Sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at Sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java : 90)
.
.
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)

```
private static int getIncrementValue(int x, int y){
 int base = 100;
 int range = 0;
 if(x < 0){
   range = x;
   range = y + Math.abs(range);
 }else{
   range = y;
}
int inc = (range) /6;
if((range / 10) == 0){
base = 1;
} else if ((range / 100 <= 10){
base = 10;
}
inc = roundToHundred(inc)
if((inc * 6) <= range) {
while((inc * 6) <= range){
inc += base;
}
}
return inc;
}
}
```

I am really clueless on what could be the issue here. as the while loop deals with only the primitive stack memory values. Can someone shed some light on what else could be the possibility in this case.

**Note :** This issue is not happening everytime. It happens only twice or thrice in a Month.

Comment: I intrinsically distrust static methods and their member vars in multithreaded apps:(

Comment: I mean, why static?  Can the threads not instantiate an object so you can get rid of the static, class methods??

Comment: Hi MartinJames. That is a Utility Function and it is part of a Util Groovy Class. Since this is a Util function it is made static. Could you shed some light on the perspective you see this issue, because of which you distrust static Methods in Multithreaded Apps.

Answer (score 0):

WSVR0605W is not an error, just a notification. If a thread has been busy for a long interval, it may be hung, so WebSphere provides this notification for the information of the system operator.

The interval at which the notification is triggered is configurable, see:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/ttrb_confighangdet.html